# Switch statement not executing as expected

Tags: c++

Entering input to get correct amount total. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        float cost2 = 0;
        char ch;

        cout << "1. Water \t\tRs.10" << endl;
        cout << "2. Cola \t\tRs.20" << endl;
        cout << "3. Lemonade \t\tRs.15" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: " << endl;

        cin >> ch;
        switch(ch) {
        case 1: {
            cost2 += 10; // trying to add 10 if input (ch) is 1
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cost2 += 20;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            cost2 += 15;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "The total before tax is: Rs." << cost2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: `ch` is a `char`.  `1` is an `int`.  Change `case 1` to `case '1'` and it'll work.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks a lott you were right!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
case 1: {
```

to:

```
case '1': {
```

and do the same for all cases, since `ch` variable is of type `char`. As a result, you should compare it with a character. When you say `case 1`, you can imagine it like saying `if(ch == 1)`, which doesn't make sense. You would like `1` in that if condition to get the expected result. It's the same for the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        float cost2 = 0;
        char ch;

        cout << "1. Water \t\tRs.10" << endl;
        cout << "2. Cola \t\tRs.20" << endl;
        cout << "3. Lemonade \t\tRs.15" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: " << endl;

        cin >> ch;
        cout<< ch<<endl;
        switch(ch) {
        case '1': {
            cost2 += 10; // trying to add 10 if input (ch) is 1
            break;
        }
        case '2': {
            cost2 += 20;
            break;
        }
        case '3': {
            cost2 += 15;
            break;
        }

    }
    cout << "The total before tax is: Rs." << cost2 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hey Sandip, correct answer as well! However, you should indent your code and (at least a bit of) an explanation. :)